# I'm trying to change the value of a div with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

```
<div id='right_side'>
<div id='T' title='<?php echo $u; ?> Friends'>
    <div id="f">
        <h6>
            <?php echo $u; ?> Friends
        </h6>
    </div>
</div>
<div id='users' onclick="chat();">
    <?php echo $friend; ?>

</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script> 
function chat()
{ 
    var chatbox = document.getElementById("chatbox"); 
    var chatbox = document.getElementById("chatbox").value= "<?php echo $friend_username; ?>"; 
    if(chatbox.style.display == "none"){ 
        chatbox.style.display = "block"; 
        $('#chatbox').attr("chatbox","<?php echo $friend_username; ?>"); 
    } else { 
        chatbox.style.display = "none"; chatbox.attr.value = "none"; 
    }
} 
</script>
```

I want to change the div value to the user name of the friend if you click their name.

Comment: here is the JavaScript 

<script>
function chat(){
   var chatbox = document.getElementById("chatbox");
   var chatbox = document.getElementById("chatbox").value= "<?php echo $friend_username; ?>";
   if(chatbox.style.display == "none"){
    chatbox.style.display = "block";
    $('#chatbox').attr("chatbox","<?php echo $friend_username; ?>");
    
   } else {
    chatbox.style.display = "none";
    chatbox.attr.value = "none";
  }}
</script>

Comment: Please edit he additional code into your question

Comment: how do you edit as a code??

Comment: Tip: You should use jQyery for DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to change the div value to the user name of the friend if you click their name.

Use a button (not a div) to monitor presses, and include their username in a data attribute:

```
<button type="button" data-user="Bob" class="add-user">Bob</button>
```

Then your jQuery can look like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.add-user', function(){
  // Get the username from the data attribute
  var usr = $(this).data('user');
  // Update the div's HTML
  $('#chatbox').html(usr);
});
```

Comment: @user3322253 A `div` should not have a value, only content. Also, it shouldn't have `style="display:none"` if you intend to display it!

Comment: so in the div I put a form in the div so how how will this work if you want to send messages back and forth with each other. like on Facebook chat menu

Answer (score 0):

A `div` has no `value`, therefore the desire of changing the `value` of a div is invalid. If your `chatbox` is a `div` indeed, then you should restructure your code, to use an `input`, a `textarea`, or something like that which will have a `value` or to change the inner text of the `div`.